# How to use 'customFilter' in Record Feed Elements Rest callout?

Tags: rest-api, chatter-feed, casefeed

I am trying to query feed-elements via Rest API from the workbench. [API ref](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_resource_feeds_record.htm)

```
/services/data/v51.0/chatter/feeds/record/5001x00000CA8IGAA1/feed-elements?customFilter=CustomFeed
```

I am getting this error.

```
[ {
  "errorCode" : "INVALID_FIELD",
  "message" : "Invalid custom filter name. "
} ]
```

This CustomFeedFilter is already available in ORG.

```
<types>
    <members>CustomFeed</members>
    <name>CustomFeedFilter</name>
</types>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks the 'recordId' mentioned in query doesn't exists in your org.  I tried with same Id and got similar error.

[image]
Please re-check the record id and use below query, you should be able to get results.

```
/services/data/v51.0/chatter/feeds/record/09Z6F0000004ddv/feed-elements
```

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Hi @Vinay The `/services/data/v51.0/chatter/feeds/record/09Z6F0000004ddv/feed-elements` URL  is working fine, I am getting the results with base API query. But when I am passing the `customFilter=CustomFeed` params I am getting the error.

Comment: I don't think this is the right format to pass,  even when I tried using customFilter=CustomFeed I get the error.  Also haven't found anything related documentation about error syntax.